# Capture image on current drawing state

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

What I'm trying to do is get an image after it be zoomed or moved but it's not working, the image is always the original one.

My code (not working):

```
mImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mImageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmBg = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
bmBg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmBg, 0, 0, bmBg.getWidt(), bmBg.getHeight());
mImageView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Use ImageView as presenting an image to UI. Zoom/Scale the actual image in code manually without UI/ImageView. You will also have some issues if trying using UI views to do app logic.

Comment: could you be more specific? I don't understand well what are you trying to say

Comment: I am trying to say, use Bitmap and canvas, and not mImageView.getDrawingCache() to get the final result. If you have a bitmap originally, then you zoom it with ImageView, and then trying to get result, why would you need ImageView in the middle?